# How to embed an XLS in a Joomla page?

Tags: xml, excel, joomla

I need to know how to embed a Excel spreadsheet in a Joomla site.

Answer (score 1):

Depends exactly what you mean by "embed", but you could look at [PHPExcelReader](http://mattkruse.com/2008/12/24/php-excel-reader/).

Answer (score 0):

Export it to googledocs, and embed it with the plugin for embedding googledocs inside joomla articles.